# Pyautogui not showing largest coordinate

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

With pyautogui and tkinter I wrote a script that gives me the current mouse position. Every thing works fine but it does not show the coordinate 1920x1080 instead the maximum is 1919x1079. However the script can show the smallest coordinate 0x0. What's wrong with this?

```
    def mouse_pos(self):
        mouse_xy = pyautogui.position()
        self.xy_label['text'] = str(mouse_xy)
        self.xy_label.after(10, self.mouse_pos)
```

Comment: numbers `0-1919` gives you 1920 values. Normally you use `1-1920` and you also   have 1920 values. There is nothing wrong with this. If you expects numbers `0-1920`  then you will have 1921 values.

Comment: Oh, so the term we usually use, 1920x1080, counts from 1?

Comment: yes. Normally people count from `1` but Python normally counts from `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of PyAutoGui's FAILSAFE system! The FAILSAFE system doesn't capture co-ordinates on the corner of the screen, and it doesn't let the mouse click on the corner of the screen. Try this code instead:

```
def mouse_pos(self):
        pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
        mouse_xy = pyautogui.position()
        self.xy_label['text'] = str(mouse_xy)
        self.xy_label.after(10, self.mouse_pos)
```